# Python arguments and kwargs - is it a preference issue, or is there an actual behavior difference?

Tags: python

Assume two functions, where you do it by default value of function,

```
def foo_def(name = "Default Name" , age = 10) :

    print (f"my name is {name} and I am {age}.")
```

and just take kwargs, but maybe check it later

```
def foo_kwargs(**kwargs) :
    name = kwargs.get('name') if kwargs.get('name') != None else "Default Name"
    age = kwargs.get('age') if kwargs.get('age') != None else 10

    print (f"my name is {name} and I am {age}.")
```

Now in my "opinion" for sure the first code has higher readability, and for usage of typing it's probably much favored way of coding, although this probably falls in "opinion" category.

Now my question is :

1. Are there actual behavior difference? for example, if I'm basically 'for sure' that this code will not be maintained by anyone else and will be kept short, is it fine to code like `foo_kwargs?` Is there any risk of unexpected behavior by using `**kwargs` instead of having it has an actual argument?
2. Is `**kwarg` basically only meant for exceptional case such as decorators?
3. What's the main purpose of having `**kwargs` in normal cases? is there any practical difference in having actual dict object passed as option argument vs using `**kwargs`?

Some of this question may look quite opinion based, but I'm curious if it's actually "opinion" based (please let me know, if so), or there's some hidden risk / behavior difference so one method is probably strictly better/recommended than the other.

Comment: One maybe significant difference is if you actually pass `None` as an argument: `foo_def(name=None)` vs `foo_kwargs(name=None)`. You can make them similar by using `name = kwargs.get('name', "Default Name")` instead of the `if/else`

Comment: @MarkMeyer Wow I haven't thought about it. If i coded like `foo_kwargs` it would have a hidden risk if i had something like `foo_kwargs(name="me", age=10, pet=None)` would actually put me on having a pet even if i didn't have one.. 
"

Comment: You likely want `name = kwargs.get("name", "Default Name")` to get the same behavior.

Comment: Your question appears to be three questions.

Comment: For your own code, its personal preference. A difference is that in your first example, python would error if you used an undefined parameter. Another is that IDEs would have a harder time with hints.

Comment: `**kwargs` is for when you don't know at compile time what keyword arguments might be used. One of the biggest uses is to accept unexpected arguments in order to pass them on to a method called via `super()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very big behavioral difference, and that's how they handle positional and extra arguments. Consider:

```py
def f_normal(a, b):
    return (a, b)

def f_kwargs(**kwargs):
    return (kwargs["a"], kwargs["b"])

f_normal(1, 2) # can use positional arguments as well
f_normal(name = 1, age = 2, extra = 3) # unexpected keyword argument
f_kwargs(1, 2) # this doesn't work
f_kwargs(name = 1, age = 2, extra = 3) # extra parameter ignored
```

In addition, having the accepted parameter names in the parameter list directly gives more power to language analysis features, such as VSCode displaying function signatures when hovering over a function call. The main purpose of `**kwargs` is for when you want to accept **any** keyword argument, and you don't know the names beforehand, such as the `dict` constructor:

```py
dict(a=1, b=2) # {"a": 1, "b": 2}
```